# PowerShell foreach, First expression runs once and the next expressions runs in loop

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach

In the below PowerShell statement, looks like the first expression in {} runs once where as the second expression in {} runs for each of the pipeline output, why?

```
1..5 | foreach{ write-host "Run Once!!" }{ write-host "Loop"}
```

Output:
Run Once!!
Loop
Loop
Loop
Loop
Loop

Any specific reason why the first expression after foreach runs only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you write it makes it run like advanced function **BEGIN/PROCESS/END** construct. Like so:

```
PS C:\> 1..5 | foreach -Begin{ write-host 'Run Once!!' }-Process { write-host 'Loop'} -End{Write-Host 'Finished!'}
Run Once!!
Loop
Loop
Loop
Loop
Loop
Finished!
```

You want to do this when you do something specific that requires several steps process, like so:

```
BEGIN
{
  Connect to something
}
   PROCESS
   {
     Do number of things
   }
END
{
  Disconnect
}
```